# Obtaining a lot of database linked objects faster

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application that is getting a lot of data from database filling internal structures of my program. The problem is that it takes a lot of time. The process is very long because of multiple select queries during iterations on nested structures. Right now I am thinking of making a bigger query with a lot of JOINS.

In this example I am getting a collection of `EventDefinitions`.

The `EventDefinitions` table is joined to

1. `EventMonitorTags` - one `Tag` to many `EventDefinitions`
2. `EventRecipients` - one `Recipient` to many `EventDefinitions`
3. `EventReports` - one `Report` to many `EventDefinitions`

Let me show you some code that needs optimisation:

```
public static List<DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition> GetEventDefinitionCollection(bool getReportsAndRecipients, int plcNumber, bool onlyActiveEvents)
    {
        List<DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition> eventDefinitionCollection = new List<DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition>();

        string dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM EventDefinitions ed LEFT JOIN Tags t ON ed.triggerTagId = t.tagId";


        using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DbConnectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition eventDefinition = FillEventDefinition(dbReader);

                        if (eventDefinition.EventActive | !onlyActiveEvents)
                        {
                            GetEventMonitorTags(ref eventDefinition);

                            if (getReportsAndRecipients)
                            {
                                GetEventReports(ref eventDefinition);
                                GetEventRecipients(ref eventDefinition);
                            }

                            eventDefinitionCollection.Add(eventDefinition);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return eventDefinitionCollection;
    }
```

And then there is a code to get nested structures for each EventDefinition structure:

```
private static void GetEventMonitorTags(ref DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition eventDefinition)
    {
        MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DbConnectionString);
        using (dbConnection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            string dbQuery = "SELECT tagId FROM EventMonitorTags WHERE eventDefinitionId = " + eventDefinition.Id;
            eventDefinition.MonitorTags = new ArrayList();

            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        int monitorTagId = (int)dbReader["tagId"];
                        DatabaseStructures.Tag tag = Tags.Get(monitorTagId);

                        eventDefinition.MonitorTags.Add(tag);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetEventReports(ref DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition eventDefinition)
    {
        MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DbConnectionString);
        using (dbConnection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            string dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM EventReports WHERE eventDefinitionId = " + eventDefinition.Id;
            eventDefinition.ReportDefinitions = new ArrayList();

            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        int reportDefinitionId = (int)dbReader["reportDefinitionId"];
                        DatabaseStructures.ReportDefinition reportDefinition = ReportsDefinition.Get(reportDefinitionId);

                        eventDefinition.ReportDefinitions.Add(reportDefinition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetEventRecipients(ref DatabaseStructures.EventDefinition eventDefinition)
    {
        MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DbConnectionString);
        using (dbConnection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            string dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM EventRecipients WHERE eventDefinitionId = " + eventDefinition.Id;
            eventDefinition.Recipients = new ArrayList();

            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        int recipientId = (int)dbReader["recipientId"];
                        DatabaseStructures.Recipient recipient = Recipients.Get(recipientId);

                        eventDefinition.Recipients.Add(recipient);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In each of this method another one is called to get the right object. In this case I show only one:

```
public static DatabaseStructures.Tag Get(int tagId)
    {
        DatabaseStructures.Tag tag = new DatabaseStructures.Tag();
        string dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE tagId = " + tagId;

        MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DbConnectionString);
        using (dbConnection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConnection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        tag = FillTag(dbReader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return tag;
    }
```

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: So I should build one big query to get all the data to my code and then split it into structures?

Comment: Another idea is to make all those Gets lazy, so your application would only query for them when needed.

Comment: In the end there will be a join of 7 tables: EventDefinitions, EventMonitorTags, Tags, EventRecipients, Recipients, EventReports, Reports

Comment: Yes it's a complex scenario indeed :-) perhaps instead of getting everything at once, you could get only what you need at the moment you need it. Async can be your friend too.

Comment: i am cleaning up my comments so we don't keep trash here. :-)

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure thing, it's hard to really help without knowing the scope of your application, what you do with the data when you get it and if you really need all that data at once. :-)